# How to find the VS code extension that is giving bad auto import suggestions all the time whenever I press ctrl + space

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Annoying extension that is ruining my VS code]

I have been searching & trying to know what is the extension causing this strange behavior, suggesting auto imports all the time in all the wrong places

I have searched my extensions to the best of my knowledge but didn't find any extension with a similar look or claiming to do auto imports ...

Does anyone know how to know what is the extension that is giving some output, like this list of suggestions in the snapshot?

This extension is flooding me with bad suggestions & making the useful suggestion get lost, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK I thought I won't find it on my own but then it was this extension (Auto Import - ES6, TS, JSX, TSX)

I totally appreciate the effort in that extension but it flooded my suggestions so I had to remove it, the snapshot was showing another import icon that is why I thought it was another extension, turned out that VS code has a very good native support to the auto import.

Hope this helps someone else.

[image: the extension that flooded my suggestions in typescript]